# Is the signature of a matrix with a "Zero Quadrant" always zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to figure out how to prove that the signature of a matrix in the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&A\\B&C\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&A\\B&C\end{bmatrix}^T=\begin{bmatrix}0&A+B^T\\B+A^T&C+C^T\end{bmatrix}
$$
is always $0$. $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all $g\times g$ matrices, and $M^T$ denotes the transpose of a matrix. The transposition of the matrix is added so that the matrix ends up being symmetric in the end. I have tried to build some sort of characteristic polynomial to try and prove that there are always an equal number of positive and negative roots, but I can't seem to get anywhere.

I've only had one course on linear algebra, so this sort of thing might be outside the scope of my abilities, and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Take $C=I$ and $A=B=0$

Comment: I would love to (and that would make things easier), but what exactly allows me to do so?

Comment: @The_Scientist___ Will's point is that your statement is not correct. With the particular choice of $A,B,C$ suggested, the signature of the matrix is not zero.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: *"I have tried to build some sort of characteristic polynomial to try and prove that there are always an equal number of positive and negative roots."*  If you apply Cauchy Eigenvalue Interlacing to the leading $g\times g$ principal submatrix, you see your matrix on the right must have (at least) $g$ eigenvalues $\geq 0$ and (at least) $g$ eigenvalues $\leq 0$.  This is a small refinement of your statement.